# MVC Binding to Entity Called Area

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, binding

I have a database entity called `Area`. In my `Create` model I have the following code:

```
public Entities.Entities.Area Area { get; set; }
```

and then in my view I just have an input for each of the properties in `Area`.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Area.Name)
```

When I save the form the `Area` object is being passed back as null. But when I change the `Area` object name in my `Create` model and update the references in the view it then saves.

```
public Entities.Entities.Area AreaDetail { get; set; }

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AreaDetail.Name)
```

Why does the binding fail when the Area object was simply named Area? Does it have something to do with the MVC Area? If so, how would that mess up the bindings?

Answer (score 2):

i have done the same with class name **AREA**,it works perfectly, here is the code

the GET method

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ByReleasedDate()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

the POST method

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ByReleasedDate(CreateModel model)
    {
        return Content($"Area name is {model.Area.Name}");
    }
```

the Create Model

```
public class CreateModel
{
    public Area Area { get; set; }
}
```

the area Model

```
public class Area
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Proof for post method 
[image: Proof for post method]